# Short URLs for cstheory

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I have created

> [j.mp/cstheory](http://j.mp/cstheory)
>
> [j.mp/cstheorySE](http://j.mp/cstheorySE)

Feel free to use them.

Comment: Thanks @Kaveh! Are these links permanent?

Comment: How does this work for links to actual pages ?

Comment: @Hsien-Chih Chang, yes, they are, and they cannot be modified to direct to any other URL (if understood their FAQ correctly).

Comment: @Suresh, I don't think they will work for questions (something like `j.mp/cstheory/q/6651/`) since they are for fixed URLs. It could work if there was a way to give the postid as a parameter, something like `j.mp/cstheory?postid=6651`.

Comment: @Suresh, I posted [a feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91996/153230).

Comment: Please note that something like `cstheory.XXX.XXX/q/6651` would be *shorter* than `j.mp/cstheory?postid=6651`! If only we had a shorter version of stackexchange.com, the problem would be solved permanently for all sites.

Comment: Incidentally, `qa.sigact.org/q/6651` would be even shorter than that, and much more professional-looking...

Comment: @Jukka, one could have `j.mp/cstheory?6651`, but your suggestions are better, maybe you should post the request for a general shorter URL for SE network to MetaSO. :)